# Making a div full screen in SPFx webpart deployed in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, spfx, spfx-webparts

I need to make a div full screen (in web page) and for that I am using CSS.

```
.divFullScreen {
    display: block;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The above CSS works when I test on the `workbench.aspx` and the div occupies full screen on web page. But when I deploy my SPFx webpart and add it to page, the CSS does not work as it works in `workbench.aspx`. The div ends up occupying a very small section.

On inspection, there are div's with classes `ControlZone` and `Canvas` which are parent to the SPFx webpart. I tried modfying there styles but doesn't seems to work.

What is the best way to make a div full screen in SPFx webpart?

Comment: What do you mean by "the css fails"?

Comment: @Nils: It means that is does not work as it works on `workbench.aspx`. I will update the question.